# How to get the Objects of TabBar Tabs in Android?

Tags: android, tabbar

In Android App, I am using a TabBar which consists of 4 tabs. I have a requirement to get all objects of 4 Tabs. How can achieve this, any suggestions.

Comment: Hi Sergey Glotov,for every tab i have attached one Activity,so for all the four tabs i have four activites.I want to retrieve these objects,so that i can call the methods in the Activity class

Answer (score 0):

```
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // This is the Object of TabBar
        Intent intent;

        // Single Activity
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Home.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getResources().getString(R.string.Home)).setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.Home),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Now you can add different tabs like this

Comment: Dev,the above code is used to add the tabs.In the above you have used on Activity named Home.Here i want to retrieve the Home object in Tab bar class.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two obvious approaches:

1. Use the functions a [`LocalActivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html) (which should be available in every `ActivityGroup`, hence also in `TabActivity`) provides to retrieve the activities. You can get either the currently selected `Activity` through calling `getCurrentActivity()` or any by passing in the tag that was used as part of the `TabSpec`: `getActivity(String id)`.
2. Build your own local mapping of tags against activities and use those for lookups; for example a `Map<String, Activity>`.

In both cases you'll need to cast the generic `Activity` to your own implementation in order to access your own methods. If the activities should all implement similar methods, I'd advice you to use an interface which declares those methods, and use that interface for casting/mapping; e.g `Map<String, ITabbedActivity>`.

Alternatively you could simply keep track of the different activities using one member variable per `Activity`. That way you can avoid casting. Not that if you're dealing with more than four tabs, I wouldn't recommend taking this approach.